# Jquery checked not firing on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My jQuery code is not firing on page load. However once the page is loaded and then if I toggle the radio button it works. I am fairly new to jQuery and ASP.Net hence I have no clue where I am going wrong. I tried `onload=""` but I couldn't figure out for life of me how to call default jQuery function which doesn't have any name in that onload code block.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        var SelectedValue = $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        if (SelectedValue == 1) {
            //If cash is selected then hide the Div
            $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "none");
            $('#MetaType').css("display", "none");
            $('#TextBox7').css("display", "none");
            $('#MetaSize').css("display", "none");
            //or you can simply use jQuery hide method to hide the Div as below:
            //$('#dvShowHide').hide();          
        }
        else {
            //If Cheque is selected then show the Div
            $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "block");
            $('#MetaType').css("display", "block");
            $('#TextBox7').css("display", "block");
            $('#MetaSize').css("display", "block");
            //or you can simply use jQuery show method to show the Div as below:
            //$('#dvShowHide').show();
            //Clear textboxes
            $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').val('');

            //Set focus in bank name textbox
            $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Which code do you want to execute onload? the jquery code i see is on click event that is why it is not executing onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a `click` handler on load of the page you can `trigger()` the event:

```
$('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    // your code here...
}).click(); // < trigger the event on load
```

You can also use `.trigger('click');`

Alternatively you can separate your logic out to its own function which is called on the click of the button and the load of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').click(checkState); // onclick
    checkState(); // onload
});

function checkState() {
    var SelectedValue = $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    if (SelectedValue == 1) {
        //If cash is selected then hide the Div
        $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "none");
        $('#MetaType').css("display", "none");
        $('#TextBox7').css("display", "none");
        $('#MetaSize').css("display", "none");
        //or you can simply use jQuery hide method to hide the Div as below:
        //$('#dvShowHide').hide();          
    }
    else {
        //If Cheque is selected then show the Div
        $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "block");
        $('#MetaType').css("display", "block");
        $('#TextBox7').css("display", "block");
        $('#MetaSize').css("display", "block");
        //or you can simply use jQuery show method to show the Div as below:
        //$('#dvShowHide').show();
        //Clear textboxes
        $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').val('');

        //Set focus in bank name textbox
        $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude it worked like a charm :) I really appreciate everybody's help who replied :) matty and tushar :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To run that logic on page load, you're best off extracting it out into a function, then call the function, something like:

```
$(function () {
    setValue();
    $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').click(setValue);
});


function setValue()
{
    var SelectedValue = $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    if (SelectedValue == 1) {
        //If cash is selected then hide the Div
        $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "none");
        $('#MetaType').css("display", "none");
        $('#TextBox7').css("display", "none");
        $('#MetaSize').css("display", "none");
        //or you can simply use jQuery hide method to hide the Div as below:
        //$('#dvShowHide').hide();          
    }
    else {
        //If Cheque is selected then show the Div
        $('#DropDownList1').css("display", "block");
        $('#MetaType').css("display", "block");
        $('#TextBox7').css("display", "block");
        $('#MetaSize').css("display", "block");
        //or you can simply use jQuery show method to show the Div as below:
        //$('#dvShowHide').show();
        //Clear textboxes
        $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').val('');

        //Set focus in bank name textbox
        $('#<%=TextBox7.ClientID %>').focus();
    }
}
```