# bootstrap jquery asp.net spacing issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

using [Jquery checked not firing on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915717/jquery-checked-not-firing-on-page-load/29915850#29915850) above mentioned code I am displaying and hiding textbox using radio button.

Problem I have is when radio button is selected as No there is more empty space in the end as compared to when it is selectd yes.

i am using bootstrap cssstyle .

Comment: can you show us your HTML, it looks like an element is not closed correctly.

Comment: My guess is one of the hidden inputs is set to `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`. It should be `display:none`,  otherwise it still takes up space even if you can't see it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4RgMSs8r

Comment: I have pasted the complete code above .

Comment: I have tried to double check and all the elements seem to have been closed properly and is display:none everywhere